# Trigger inside Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to trigger function only when Ajax success

my function ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            console.dir(msg);    
            if(msg.status == 'OK'){
                $("#fb-root").on("facebook:init", function(event, response) {
                   if(response.status === 'connected') {
                      alert("LOG")
                   }else{
                      alert(" NO LOG ");
                   }
                });
          }
        }
    });
```

Trigger Function

```
function getLoginStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);

        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);
        } else {
            $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);
        }
    });
}
```

Never `alert("LOG")` or `alert("NO LOG");`

if i use

```
$("#fb-root").on("facebook:init", function(event, response) {
    if(response.status === 'connected') {
        alert("LOG")
    }else{
        alert(" NO LOG ");
    }
});
```

outside ajax, it's works

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
    //Move this function outside ajax as this is to register event handler, not to trigger the function.
    $("#fb-root").on("facebook:init", function(event, response) {
        if(response.status === 'connected') {
            alert("LOG")
        }else{
            alert(" NO LOG ");
        }
    });

    function getLoginStatus() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);
            } else {
                $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',[response]);
            }
        });
    }

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            console.dir(msg);    
            if(msg.status == 'OK'){
                 getLoginStatus(); //only trigger the function when ajax is successful.
               //or  $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',msg);
            }
        }
    });
```

`$("#fb-root").on("facebook:init"` is to register event handler, not to trigger event. You should always add the event handler outside $.ajax function and trigger it to fire inside your success function.

Comment: That's a big wodge of code. What have you changed? Please don't make people play spot-the-difference.

Comment: @Quentin: I added more text and comments in the answer.

Comment: @Barno: sorry, I cannot access your link

Comment: `$("#fb-root").on("facebook:init", function(event, response) {
                    if(response.status === 'connected') {                        check(response.authResponse.userID,response.authResponse.accessToken,msg.facebook_secret,false);
                    }else{
                        $(".share_facebook").prop("checked",false);
                        
                    }
                });`

Comment: i need msg.faceboo‌​k_secret after success and use with trigger function

Comment: @Barno: I'm not sure if calling `$('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init',msg);` inside `success` is what you need.